# font size in presentation made by python-pptx

Tags: python, python-pptx

how to change size of text on slide.
I don't know why, but by default the text size is 32. Sorry for my bad English.
Here is my code:

```
    TEXT = ['''Help on method shuffle in module random:

    shuffle(x, random=None) method of random.Random instance
        Shuffle list x in place, and return None.

        Optional argument random is a 0-argument function returning a
        random float in [0.0, 1.0); if it is the default None, the
        standard random.random will be used.''', '''Help on method choice in         
    module random:

    choice(seq) method of random.Random instance
        Choose a random element from a non-empty sequence.''', '''Help on 
    method randint in module random:

    randint(a, b) method of random.Random instance
        Return random integer in range [a, b], including both end         
    points.''']
    NAMES = ['shuffle', 'choice', 'randint']


    from pptx import Presentation
    prs = Presentation()
    slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[1]
    for i in range(3):
        slide = prs.slides.add_slide(slide_layout)
        title = slide.placeholders[0]
        content = slide.placeholders[1]
        title.text = NAMES[i]
        content.text = TEXT[i]
    prs.save('test.pptx')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This topic is covered in the documentation here:
http://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/text.html

The short version is that if you want to control text formatting (font properties) you need to work at the *run* level (one level below *paragraph*), which is where text formatting is applied.